# Is it possible to hide all layers except a selected layer and then show all layers that were "previously visible"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is a feature I need very often as sometimes I am uncertain with some objects on the page so I leave them hidden.  When I use the "Show/Hide all other layers" this feature is not useful to me as it is dumb logic and doesn't remember my hidden layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the **Option/Alt** key when clicking the visibility icon next to a specific layer in the **Layers Panel**.

This will *toggle visibility* for all *other* layers.

If a layer was *already* set to "off" before the initial Option/Alt-click, when you toggle things back on, it will remain set to "off".

Comment: Legend! Thank you!